# JPQL/HQL ERROR: syntax error at end of input with LEFT JOIN

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm getting *ERROR: syntax error at end of input* while trying to execute the query below:

```
SELECT appointment FROM Appointment appointment LEFT JOIN DoctorFacilityAppointment dfa
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Appointment class

```java
public class Appointment implements Serializable {
        
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
        
   @Column(name="start_time")
   private LocalDateTime startTime;
        
   @Column(name="is_valide")
   private boolean isValid;
        
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Patient patient;
    
}
```

DoctorFacilityAppointment

```java
public class DoctorFacilityAppointment implements Serializable {
        
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
        
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private Appointment appointment;
        
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_service_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   private DoctorFacility doctorFacility;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL/HQL [join](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join) should refer to the appropriate entity's association or component/embedded attributes.

So, the correct query should look like this:

```
select app from DoctorFacilityAppointment dfa left join dfa.appointment app
```